# How to use OAuth with Geofence to restrict layers?

Tags: geoserver, authentication, geoserver-geofence

So I'm currently using GeoFence and OpenLayers and have 2 roles: GIS and REGULAR user roles. They both see different things. They authenticate themselfes in OpenLayers client via basic auth.
I would like to add OAuth to the client side and also to the geoserver. I set up the OAuth in both places but I don't know how to connect the different roles to different email addresses.
So all logged in accounts behave the same way.
How can I tell the geoserver to associate the user1@gmail.com and user2@gmail.com to the GIS role and associate all other email addresses to the REGULAR role?

Comment: I would like to know more detail on this too!